# Magento2 reindexing CE vs EE

Tags: magento2, reindex, magento-community, magento2-enterprise

What are main differences in Magento indexing between Magento Community Edition 2.x and Enterprise Edition 2.x?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

None. They use the same processes in Magento 2.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Ryan Hoerr. This question is on the Study Guide for the Magento 2 Solution Specialist Certification exam. I was wondering if there is no difference why they put that question there! Is there also no difference on the admin panel? Like in M1 CE you were able to reindex from the admin panel but in M1 EE you were not able to do that.

Comment: M2 EE has additional indexes: "Product/Target Rule", "Target/Product Rule", "Sales Rule". Otherwise everything is the same, even in the admin panel interface. It's probably an intentional trick question, since, as you noted, there was a difference between them in M1.

Comment: How to improve reindexing Magento 2.3.3 [EE]?

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference in indexing of M2 CE and M2 EE except that of number of indexes.

If you will look into the table '*indexer_state*' , both for CE and EE , you will find the difference.

```
SELECT * FROM `indexer_state`
```

**CE**:

```
1) cataloginventory_stock 2) catalogrule_product 3) catalogrule_rule 
4) catalogsearch_fulltext 5) catalog_category_product 
6)catalog_product_attribute 7) catalog_product_category 8) catalog_product_price 
9) customer_grid 10) design_config_grid
```

**EE**:

```
1) cataloginventory_stock 2) catalogrule_product 3) catalogrule_rule 
4) catalogsearch_fulltext 5) catalog_category_product 
6)catalog_product_attribute 7) catalog_product_category 8) catalog_product_price 
9) customer_grid 10) design_config_grid 
11) salesrule_rule 12) targetrule_product_rule 13) targetrule_rule_product (These 3 are additional)
```

[Source Blog](https://ahmadvaqaskhan.blogspot.in/2018/01/magento-2-reindexing-ce-vs-ee.html)